# swagger-Unrecognized response type; displaying content as text

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger

I built a swagger using swagger-ui-express module  for my node js backend.
I have an endpoint that returns files ( pdf-doc or xlsx).
When i test my endpoint on swagger it rturns me 200 response with always this message on body 'Unrecognized response type; displaying content as text.'
This is my swagger endpoint's code.

[image: endpoint response image]

```
 "/reports?typeDoc={typeDoc}&file={file}": {
            "get": {
                "tags": [
                    "Generate report"
                ],
                "description": "",
                "operationId": "",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "typeDoc",
                        "in": "path",
                        "description": "type of document",
                        "required": true,
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "file",
                        "in": "path",
                        "description": "name of the file",
                        "required": true,
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "200":{
                    "description": "Report generated succefully. ",
                    "content":{
                        "application/octet-stream":{
                            "schema":{
                                "type": "string",
                                "format": "binary"}
                        }
                    }
                    },
                    "500": {
                        "description": "Error in zip file structure or typeDoc"
                    }
                }
            }   
    }
```

Comment: Probably unrelated, but your Swagger spec is not valid and uses a mix of OpenAPI 2.0 and OpenAPI 3.0 syntax. If you paste it into https://editor.swagger.io it will show where the errors are. Did you write the spec manually or is it generated from source code?

Comment: 1) What version of Swagger UI do you use? Open the browser dev tools > Console and evaluate `versions`. 2) Can you share a link to the actual endpoint you are calling if it's public, so that others can reproduce the issue?

Comment: no it is a local endpoint :/ i use version 2.0

Answer (score 15):

Try add headers like

```
content-disposition: attachment; filename = test.xlsx
content-type: multipart / form-data
```

and swagger-ui will understand the response type and offer download the file.

[image]

Comment: What about `video/mp4` files?

Comment: You can try it yourself and see the result, but you need to understand that Swagger UI is evolving and may not recognize all types at the moment. In this case, you can contact the developers - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues.

Answer (score 12):

Swagger UI has an [open issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5500) for this. As a workaround add header ('filename' directive may be omitted)

```
content-disposition: attachment; filename="<some file name>"
```

Then Swagger UI will provide "Download file" link for the response body.

**Note:** content-type header should be set to the actual content type of the response (and it will be interpreted by browser while opening the download link); normally content-type of the response **should not be** 'multipart/form' as suggested by another answer.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone using **FileContentResult** or **FileStreamResult** make sure you have '*FileDownloadName*' property set.

FileContentResult:

```
var result = new FileContentResult(reader.BaseStream.ReadToEnd(),MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
result.FileDownloadName = "JEfTest.pdf";
```

FileStreamResult:

```
var result = new FileStreamResult(stream, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
result.FileDownloadName = "JEfTest.pdf";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `octet-stream` as a fallback. header should look like this:

```
content-disposition: inline; filename=sample.pdf 
content-type: application/octet-stream
```