# preview pdf in browser from controller spring boot: Unrecognized response type; displaying content as text

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pdf, swagger

I want to preview a pdf file genereted with java, but the following code gives this error

> Unrecognized response type; displaying content as text.

```
@GetMapping("/previewPDF/{codeStudent}")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> previewPDF(@PathVariable("codeStudent") String code) throws IOException {
        
        byte[] pdf = //pdf content in bytes

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();      
        headers.add("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + "example.pdf");
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(pdf); 
    }
```

UPDATE: here is a screenshot of the error
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the response PDF Media Type for your resource.

See [RFC standart](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8118.html). [Full list of Media Types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#image).

Spring documentation regarding [produces Media Type](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#produces--).

```java
    @GetMapping(value = "/previewPDF/{codeStudent}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> previewPDF(@PathVariable("codeStudent") String code) throws IOException
```

Set also PDF content type for your `ResponseEntity`

```java
    @GetMapping(value = "/previewPDF/{codeStudent}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> previewPDF(@PathVariable("codeStudent") String code) throws IOException {
        byte[] pdf = null;
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        String fileName = "example.pdf";
        headers.setContentDispositionFormData(fileName, fileName);        
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(pdf);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! but the error still there

Comment: when i tried to call this api from Postman with this url `http://localhost:8080/api/previewPDF/C15`, in the body I can see the pdf file so I'll accept your anwser, Please could this problem be related to swagger ?

Comment: Set also content type for your response entity, I have updated the answer. You need just return the proper content type to the browser. In this way browser will understand that it should display PDF

Comment: `The method contentType(MediaType) in the type ResponseEntity.BodyBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (String) Java(67108979)` I got this error in return

Comment: try this one updated example.

Comment: The same error, I upload an image (above in UPDATE section) of the error it may help

Comment: You are right this is swagger specific. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56479965/swagger-unrecognized-response-type-displaying-content-as-text

Comment: yes here is the issue https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5500. Anyways, I appreciate your help!

Comment: ddidn't help : 
 return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).contentType
                        (MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)
                .body(new InputStreamResource(inputStream));

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer directly downloads the PDF instead of doing a preview, so I had to set the `Content-Disposition` to `inline` instead.

```java
headers.setContentDisposition(
  ContentDisposition.builder("inline").filename("preview-report.pdf").build()
);
```